# How to achieve the below css animation effect

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to achieve the effect in https://wesbos.com site where

In the first line the text keeps changing as well as it expands in a cool style on hovering. I have only basic css knowledge . So any pointers or codepens to achieve the same would be helpful.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes i have gone through CSS tutorials but i dont even know how to start this. Probably i ll delete this question. thanks.

Comment: Before you delete, one way to achieve this is to make 5 identical rectangles, use absolute positioning to stack them on top of one another, and then use `transform:translate` in CSS to make them move and tilt when hovered over. However to truly make this work properly, you would require some relatively advanced CSS skills, and likely some javascript (to make the elements move, even if the mouse isn't over the specific element).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for taking time and answering this Christopher. This gives me the direction needed to start up on something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below css

```js
$(".flash").hover(function(){
var j = 1;
var i = 264;

 setInterval(function(){  
    
    $(".flash span:nth-child(" + j + ")").css("z-index", ""+ i +"");      i = i + 1;
     j = j + 1;
     if(j == 7)
     {
        j = 1;
     }
    }, 1000);
   
});
```

```css
span.flash {
    background: #ecd018;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

span.flash i {
    visibility: hidden;
}

span.flash span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #ecd018;
    transition: top 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    line-height: 50px;
}

span.flash span:first-child {
    display: inline;
    z-index: 1;
}

span.flash:hover,
span.flash.open {
    background: none;
}

span.flash:hover span,
span.flash.open span {
    transition: all 0.2s;
    top: auto;
}

span.flash:hover span.designer,
span.flash.open span.designer {
    top: -96px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
}

span.flash:hover span.developer,
span.flash.open span.developer {
    top: -44px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
}

span.flash:hover span.entrepreneur,
span.flash.open span.entrepreneur {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
    top: 0;
}

span.flash:hover span.speaker,
span.flash.open span.speaker {
    top: 52px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
}

span.flash:hover span.teacher,
span.flash.open span.teacher {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(40deg);
    transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(40deg);
    top: 92px;
}

.breif img {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .blogPost {
        width: 48%;
        margin: 1%;
    }
    .welcome .welcomeText {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.48);
        margin-left: 340px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    span.flash {
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    span.flash:hover {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(90px);
    }
    .bar {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .bar input[type="email"] {
        width: 120px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="flash">
      <i>Developer</i>
      <span class="designer" style="z-index: 265;">Designer</span>
      <span class="developer" style="z-index: 266;">Developer</span>
      <span class="entrepreneur" style="z-index: 262;">Entrepreneur</span>
      <span class="speaker" style="z-index: 263;">Speaker</span>
      <span class="teacher" style="z-index: 264;">Teacher</span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.welcome p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Raleway", serif;
}
.welcome p.subtext {
  font-size: 20px;
}
span.flash {
  background: #ecd018;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
span.flash i {
  visibility: hidden;
}
span.flash span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #ecd018;
  transition: top 0.2s;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  line-height: 50px;
}
span.flash span:first-child {
  display: inline;
  z-index: 1;
}
span.flash:hover,
span.flash.open {
  background: none;
}
span.flash:hover span,
span.flash.open span {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  top: auto;
}
span.flash:hover span.designer,
span.flash.open span.designer {
  top: -96px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
}
span.flash:hover span.developer,
span.flash.open span.developer {
  top: -44px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
}
span.flash:hover span.entrepreneur,
span.flash.open span.entrepreneur {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
  top: 0;
}
span.flash:hover span.speaker,
span.flash.open span.speaker {
  top: 52px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
}
span.flash:hover span.teacher,
span.flash.open span.teacher {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(40deg);
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(40deg);
  top: 92px;
}
```

```html
<p class="desc" style="margin-top:100px">I'm a
    <span class="flash">
      <i>Developer</i>
      <span class="designer" style="z-index: 35;">Designer</span>
      <span class="developer" style="z-index: 36;">Developer</span>
      <span class="entrepreneur" style="z-index: 37;">Entrepreneur</span>
      <span class="speaker" style="z-index: 38;">Speaker</span>
      <span class="teacher" style="z-index: 34;">Teacher</span>
    </span> making the web an awesome place.</p>
```